# Is there something invisible being called in my Bootstrap Modal (called through ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax

I have a bootstrap modal being called through ajax a couple of times on my website.

My problem is:
The modal works, but it needs to be double-clicked to get focus and can only be called once. Otherwise, the button won't open it again and the page will need to be reloaded. Is there a hidden class being called that I can't see?

Thanks for the help!

Code is below:

Button:

```
<button class="load-product-details">Product Details</button>
```

the modal is in the layout page as:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal modal-view" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Request">
</div>
```

The javascript is:

```
$(".load-product-details").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $tab = e.target.hash;
    var $itemurl = "Requests/DetailsModalView/?id=" + $(this).val();
    $.fn.CallPage($tab, $itemurl);
    return false;
});

$.fn.CallPage = function ($tab, $itemurl, isEmail = false) {
    console.log("in function");
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: $itemurl,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".modal-view").html(data);
            //turn off data dismiss by clicking out of the box and by pressing esc
            $(".modal-view").modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
            //shows the modal
            $(".modal").modal('show');
            //bootstrap dynamically adds a class of modal-backdrop which must be taken off to make it clickable
            $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    }
});
```

and the partial view being called has this structure:

```
<div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg  modal-view" role="document" style="max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto;">
    <div class="modal-content d-inline-block">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                <button type="button" class="close close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Modal body -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" name="OrderType" value="Save" asp-action="EditModalView" class="btn btn-outline-primary close-modal" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".modal-view").modal({` should be `$(".modal").modal({` as you're using `$(".modal").modal('show');` later

Comment: I suspect the issue is that both your `.modal` and your `.modal-dialog` (partial view inside .modal) have the class `.modal-view`, so any code references `$(".modal-view")` will affect both

Comment: Thanks! @freedomn-m that solved the issue of the js working again(I took out the modal-view class on the second div), but it still needs to be clicked twice to get the focus on the modal and I still need to reload the page. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need this `$(".modal-backdrop").remove();` - change the `backdrop` option to `false` if you don't want the backdrop.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options

Comment: Can you creating a working snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) to demonstrate the problem?  Might need to remove the ajax and set the html via a clone or a string.

Comment: @freedomn-m for some reason the data-backdrop tab isn't working - it does the same thing- a second click to focus on it. I'm trying to get a working snippet. thanks so much